# 2014 Honda Accord starter problem, it cannot start intermittently

Tags: honda, starting, accord, starter

My Honda according 2014 only has 38000 miles. When first time cannot started, I changed a new battery. It was good for 4 or 5 months. My car is with a key to start. Then some time it started fine. Now it ,ore often cannot start. No click noise. All light signals are good. The dealer charges a lot just for diagnoses. What I should do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  So, if I understand correctly, your turn signals work (and probably headlights too?), but when you turn the key nothing happens?  That sounds like an ignition relay or solenoid to me -- you could look up those parts and change them.  Both of them are pretty cheap and pretty easy to replace.

Answer (score 1):

My ‘02 Honda Accord has an ignition relay that went bad. Check that. On my Accord it is in the top left most part of the engine compartment. Separate from the fuses.

When it happened to me I changed the spark plugs to a noticeable performance improvement, but didn’t fix the problem. I brought it into the dealer and they identified it as the relay. Cheap part. And the cost of repairs is subtracted from the diagnoses at my Honda dealer. So if the diagnoses costs $129 but the job is only a $150 job, Honda in my past only charges the difference. Meaning you would pay the $150, and not $279. Similarly if the job is a $50 job, they would only charge you $129.